# Lightswitch updating a changeset with oData in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I just have a question around updates that require multiple operations: if each OData-based operation is an HTTP Verb executed on a single resource (like POST to insert a new Order, and PUT to Update the available qty of a product; or say a client adds a new product, as well as a new category for that new product), does that mean when one calls SaveChanges in the client, each of these changes in a changeset would be a separate network call to the OData Service, using the required POST / PUT http operations on the relevant URI's?

Or does Lightswitch somehow bypass this oData rule of a single http operation on a uri, and instead pass the entire changeset to a single oData operation, which the server then deserializes and calls the relevant data update operations on the data provider?
If so, what is that oData/http operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightSwitch makes use of [OData batch processing](http://www.odata.org/documentation/batch) to save all changes with a single HTTP request. The relevant URL to target is service/$batch

At the time of writing lightswitch actually doesn't support saving using multiple requests. [This can cause problems when using data providers that don't support batch processing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/LightSwitchDev11Beta/thread/b61ff498-63ec-49ed-9d0e-e0655e3cc92b/)

You can find more information here: http://www.odata.org/documentation/batch